# Divs in stack and filling parent div

Tags: html, css

I have next case:

```
<div id="parent" style="height:100%;">
  <div id="child1">Some content</div>
  <div id="child2">Another content</div>
</div>
```

There are two requirements:
1) Each of the child should be expanded to the parent's size (100%).
2) In some cases "child1" should be display for the user in other "child2".

So how I can implement this in css?

Comment: I don't understand what you need here. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: not possible without javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a jsfiddle for you - [FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/C6CAQ/1/)

`display:none` and `display: block` are what you are looking for.

All child divs are hidden by default (`#parent div { display: none; }`). The child you want shown (in this case `#child2`) is given `display:block` to unhide. `display: block;` also enables the child to have a height of 100%.

As some helpful people have pointed out, you would possibly need to use some PHP/javascript/jQuery depending on what you are trying to achieve. Are you using something like PHP or jQuery currently?

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1">Child 1</div>
    <div id="child2">Child 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#parent {
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px;
   background: #F00;
}

#parent div {
   background: #CCC;
   height: 100%;
   display: none;
}

#parent #child1 {
   display: none;
}

#parent #child2 {
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: 2) In some cases "child1" should be display for the user in other "child2".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#parent div {
   min-width: 100%;
}
```

Now, there are two options for hiding the divs.

1. You do this on the server side.
2. You use JS to hide the div on the client side.

CSS won't hide the elements on a condition. Unless the condition is the screen related property.

Server side:

```
if(condition == value) {
   /* write the code for the div here */
} else {
   /* don't write the div code on the first place. */
}
```

Client side is same, use JS and the same condition block of the `if else` and then show hide it.

Hint for hiding the div,

```
document.getElementById("child1").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("child1").style.display = "block"; // for showing..
```